# Is the linear algebra a way to represent the linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

If yes, then what is the representation of $f(x)=2x+1$?

> What I believe is $2x+1=0$ is a linear equation.

If that is correct, then why when we represent vectors we have to draw a line from the origin to where the vector points?

While if we want to represent the earlier equation in coordinate system, then we will not reach the origin.

I'm not good at math, I just started my journey, so excuse me if I made a big mistake.

Comment: Linear is a word that has many different meanings depending on what you mean.  $f(X)=2x+1$ is not a linear function in the sense that $f(ax+by)\neqaf(x)+bf(y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matrices and vectors to solve a *system* of linear equations *in multiple variables*.
Specifically, the generic system
$$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\dots a_{1n}x_n=b_1\\
a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\dots a_{2n}x_n=b_2\\
\vdots\\
a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+\dots a_{mn}x_n=b_m$$
where the coefficients $a_{ij}$ and also $b_j$ are fixed numbers,
can be simply expressed as
$$Ax=b$$
where $A$ is the matrix of the coefficients $a_{ij}$, $b$ is the column vector with coordinates $b_1,\dots,b_m$ and $x$ is the $n$ dimensional column vector with the indeterminates $x_i$ as its coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

[Linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) deals with vector spaces and linear mappings between them, in particular with vectors, matrices, linear equations and systems of linear equations.

$2x+1=0$ is a linear equation regarding $x$ because it is a homogenous equation and its term containing $x$ is an algebraic term regarding $x$ of degree $1$ regarding $x$.

We have to distinguish [vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)) and the kinds of vectors that are [position vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(geometry)).